# How to compare rows in pandas data frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a pandas df with two columns. One of the columns contains strings of words, the one column contains single words. I need to compare the two columns to see if strings from 'Col_1' contain words from 'Col_2' and then create another column with an index of this element.

This is what I have:

```
data = {'Col_1':  ['A B C D', 'A B C', 'A B C'], 'Col_2': ['D', 'B', 'Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
print (df)
```

This is what I need:

```
data = {'Col_1':  ['A B C D', 'A B C', 'A B C'], 'Col_2': ['D', 'B', 'C'], 'Col_2': ['3', '1', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
print (df)
```

I have been trying to iterate through columns using .iteritems() but it doesn't really help as it seems that I can't access elements in the string in 'Col_2'

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the df.apply method with the axis set to 1 so you can apply a function or lambda on a row level.

Here is example code that creates a new column with the index of the substring. If the value is -1 it means the substring was not found.

`df['Col_3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Col_1'].find(row['Col_2']), axis=1)`

The output would look like this:

```
     Col_1 Col_2  Col_3
0  A B C D     D      6
1    A B C     B      2
2    A B C     Z     -1
```